# django get_choices_display() displaying label in shell and value in view

Tags: python, django

When I try instance.get_choices_display() in shell, it is showing the label.

But, I do the same thing in the view, it is printing value.

What can be the reason?

I want the label to be returned/printed in the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the label, I believe you want to use `instance.label`.